# Count conditions within each row in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, boolean-expression

I have this dataframe:

```
   Char1  Char2  Char3
0      2      2      3
1      2      3      3
2      2      3      3
3      2      2      2
```

I need to create three columns (`_1`, `_2`, `_3`), each of which counts the occurrence of the values 1, 2 and 3 respectively in each row.

So the output would look like this:

```
   Char1  Char2  Char3  _1  _2  _3
0      2      2      3   0   2   1
1      2      3      3   0   1   2
2      2      3      3   0   1   2
3      2      2      2   0   3   0
```

For example:

- the column `_1` is always equal to 0 because there are no 1's in any row
- for the column `_2`:

  - it is equal to 2 in the first row because there are two 2's in the first row
  - it is equal to 1 in the second row because there is one 2 in the second row
  - and so on .....

How do I get to code that in Python?

I have tried this code (for `_1` only):

```
df['_1'] = df[df.Char1 == 1].sum() + df[df.Char2 == 1].sum() + df[df.Char3 == 1].sum()
```

but I get "NaN".

DF constructor:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Char1':[2,2,2,2], 'Char2':[2,3,3,2], 'Char3':[3,3,3,2]})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can iterate over `[1,2,3]` and use `eq` on axis to identify the cells with a number and `sum` across columns to get the total:

```
for num in [1,2,3]:
    df[f"_{num}"] = df[['Char1','Char2','Char3']].eq(num, axis=1).sum(axis=1)
```

Output:

```
   Char1  Char2  Char3  _1  _2  _3
0      2      2      3   0   2   1
1      2      3      3   0   1   2
2      2      3      3   0   1   2
3      2      2      2   0   3   0
```

Comment: This is a highly useful answer, and very hard to find - thank you. I've modified this approach to give me one new column that counts how many columns in each row evaluate to be true. df["TrueCount"] = df[['Char1','Char2','Char3']].eq(2, axis=1).sum(axis=1). Is there a way to us this approach with multiple conditions that are not always equal to the same thing. For example, to count Char1 > 0, Char2 == 2, Char3 != 3

Answer (score 3):

We can do this concisely by passing a dict comprehension to [`df.assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html), where the dict key is the column name and dict value is the column Series:

```
df = df.assign(**{f'_{x}': df.eq(x, axis=1).sum(axis=1) for x in [1, 2, 3]})

#    Char1  Char2  Char3  _1  _2  _3
# 0      2      2      3   0   2   1
# 1      2      3      3   0   1   2
# 2      2      3      3   0   1   2
# 3      2      2      2   0   3   0
```